# Setting up new KMS Host - what is best practice for _VLMCS DNS entry?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, kms

I have been tasked with setting up our PDC as the new KMS Host in our environment. I have a question in relation to the DNS entry for KMS Host/s.

There is an existing _VLMCS entry in _tcp for the existing host. What is best practice here as im not really sure....

Should i set up the new host, then point the DNS entry to it, or should i delete the _VLMCS entry, and then set up a new _VLMCS DNS entry for the new host..

I have ran a test in our other environment, and the DNS entry wont auto-create like MS says it does, so it is either repoint the old one, or manually create a new one. Anyone know what is best?

If i were to do either, would the process be to delete the entry, before setting up the new host, alternatively, demoting the old host before setting up the new one and then changing the DNS entry?

This is for a server 2008 R2 / Windows 8.1 environment, although i dont think OS would matter too much here.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an FYI, i am still unsure what the best practice is for this one, but here is what i did.

I demoted the old KMS host, then removed the DNS entry for it. Then promoted the new host and manually created the DNS entry for it.

All working as it should be now.